# sass with gruntjs doesn't work

Tags: javascript, css, sass, gruntjs

The livereload worked but my sass isn't output anything to my css. No error shown in the terminal. Below is my gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        watch: {
            sass: {
                files: ['components/sass/*.{scss,sass}'],
                tasks: ['sass'],
                options: {
                        livereload: true
                }

            },
            livereload: {
                files: ['**/*'],
                options: {
                    livereload: true
                }
            }
        },
        sass: {
            options: {
                sourceMap: true,
                outputStyle: 'compressed'
            },
            files: {
                'css/styles.css': 'components/sass/styles.scss'
            }
        }
    });
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['sass', 'watch']);
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-sass');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
}
```

Anything I did wrongly here?

Comment: You should look into gulp. I just started using it and it looks much cleaner than what you have here

Comment: @AbdulAhmad this question is about grunt

Comment: If you run grunt -h is the grunt sass task available? That should help you identify if it a problem with the sass plugin or the watch / live reload plugin.

Comment: @Swordfish0321 sass is available